# Scroll to in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to scroll to an element on the page after I 'show' it.  I.E. i have a very long list of users and I display them as a list.  Each element has an edit icon you can click.  On click I show the user form which is at the top of the page.  I then want to scroll to that location.

```
  // helper method to scroll
  $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
  }
```

On edit user click:

```
  $scope.editUser = function (user) {
    $scope.user = user; // set user
    $scope.setShowUserForm(true); // show edit form
    $scope.scrollTo('admin-form'); // scroll to the form
  }
```

This works great except for the first time.  I checked the DOM and my 'user-form' element is in the DOM but hidden, which is what I want.  When I click on an edit user the first time the scroll does not work.  After the first time it fails everything is fine.  I am not sure what changed.

I also set the form to show by default such that I knew it was in the DOM and visible the first time I click edit.  That did not solve my problem either.  So whether its in the DOM or not, hidden or not the first scroll to fails.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

I think I know what is going on but I have no idea how to solve it.  I am using routing in my application.  I have routes like:

/#/main
/#/admin

Its my admin page that I am using the scroll to that is causing problems.  Here is the html I want to scroll to:

```
<div id="admin-form">
...
</div>
```

The problem is when I use angular to scroll it changes my url to:

/#/admin#admin-form

When is does that it seems to hit the route controller and reload my admin page which is why the scroll does not happen.  once I am on the /#/admin#admin-form url the scroll to works because angular does not see a change in my route and does not reload the page.  But if I change my url back to /#/admin and click the button that performs the scroll to angular again changes the url to /#/admin#admin-form.

I am sure this is as expected but I have no idea how to fix it. Or if I can.

Comment: It would help to see more code. I assume you are doing this within a directive?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Angulars routing seems to pick up the change, which in my case is bad because the scrollTo reroutes me to back to the main admin page.

Scrolling and then resetting the $location.hash() so angular does not perceive a change in url seems to work.

```
 $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    $location.hash(old);
  }
```

**Edit**:

As mentioned in a comment by @theunexpected1, since `1.4.0`, Angular's `$anchorScroll` allows you to directly pass the id as a parameter without the need to update the url with the hash:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {

  // Pass the 'id' as the parameter here, the page will scroll 
  // to the correct place and the URL will remain intact.
  $anchorScroll(id);
}
```

Comment: THANKS, IT worked for me! Seems like a stupid thing to have to do for this.  And I wish this solution was next to the documentation in AngularJS.org.

Comment: +1 for this until now. Solution to this is released under 1.4.0 (Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4568). Which means $anchorScroll('hash') will scroll without updating the location hash

Comment: Even simpler for me: `$scope.scrollTo = $anchorScroll;` and call it using `ng-click="scrollTo('admin-form')"`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

I found that if I wanted to scroll to a particular element, I wasn't interested in updating the url to show what Id I was going to (e.g. #admin-form id in www.something.com/#admin-form)

So to scroll without updating the url I found you could just call anchorscroll without needing to update the location hash.

```
$anchorScroll('admin-form');
```

Comment: Are you just calling the method and adding in the class name/ID of the element you want to scroll to here? Surely it can't be that easy.

Comment: To use the words of a couple of famous meerkats "simples"

Answer (score 4):

For future reference - and anyone who came here with the same problem about scrolling but is not using ng-routes to scroll, @Ben_Lesh's answer is actually quite insightful.

I was using

```
$location.hash(id)
$anchorScroll()
```

to scroll, but also running into the same problem regarding first-time click not working. I realized that the problem was that my *first* click **set** the object visible, and then tried to scroll to it, but at the time of scroll, the element was still **not visible on the page**. Then at the end of the cycle, the page re-renders.

The second time I click, the element is now **set** to visible, so the scrolling works fine.

The solution is, after you set the boolean that makes your element visible, 
to call an

> $timeout(function() {$scope.$apply()},0)

**then** call your scroll function. This way you force the re-render before the scroll. Voila!

Comment: This does not quite always work unfortunately as you can get an error that digest is already in progress. Another solution is to use $timeout to defer the execution of scroll until the running digest finishes

Comment: You don't need to call $apply inside of a $timeout as it calls $apply behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a plunk to show off this problem.  Notice how you have to click the button twice for the message to appear?

http://plnkr.co/edit/oU3REYC2upvlPMc5ipBp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you posted a question about this on my [blog](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html) as well in the comments.

Without looking at *all* of your code, I can only guess at this, but I can tell you a few things that might help:

1. you can't scroll to a hidden element.
2. The actual scrolling is done by a $watch that is setup by $anchorScroll which is processed during the $digest.
3. Whatever you're setting up to show/hide that form element is also being processed in a $watch at $digest.

So it looks like to me that it's trying to process the scroll before it processes the value to show the form.  To fix this I'd try either refactoring the code you're using to show the form, or wrapping your $anchorScroll call in a $timeout to ensure it's excuted after the show's watch.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get a fiddle posted that reproduces the problem.  As for a timeout, is that just a best guess at here is how long I think this will take?  Would be nice if there was a callback for the 'show' call that executed when the show/digest was done, but don't think there is.

Comment: No, it would just be an "immediate" timeout: `$timeout(function(){ $anchorScroll(); });` the idea being to force angular to process a $digest and display the form before you do the scroll.

Comment: One more thing: Are you getting any errors in your console? Maybe this is something really simple, like you forgot to inject $anchorScroll or something? (Just a thought, since I can't see your code)

Comment: I updated the question.  I can see what is happening, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You're really going to need to setup a plunk or something that demonstrates the problem. It's really hard to fix a black box. I can tell you this: All of the code you've presented looks fine and works fine in every test I set up.

Comment: Problem I am having with my jsfiddle is that you cannot see the route changes as the is no url bar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33773/discussion-between-forumuser-and-blesh)