# Incorrect work of $state.go when $location.hash is defined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In application I had defined a states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', ...)
    .state('edit', ...)
    .state('contact', ...)
```

On the '/edit' state I have a list with links which used to fastest navigation between sections on this state:

```
<button ng-click='goHome()'></button>

<ul>
    <li><a ng-click='scrollTo('section0')'></a></li>
    <li><a ng-click='scrollTo('section1')'></a></li>
    <li><a ng-click='scrollTo('section2')'></a></li>
</ul>

<div id='#section0'></div>
<div id='#section0'></div>
<div id='#section0'></div>

function goHome() {
    $state.go('home');
}

function scrollTo(sectionName) {
    $location.hash(sectionName);
    $anchorScroll();
}
```

When I clicked on the first link url is modified:

```
/edit --> /edit#section0
```

After I click on the button and tried go to state 'home' from current 'edit' state, then this 'edit' state is reloaded and url modified:

```
'/edit#section0' --> '/edit'
```

But it is not required 'home' state ... 
When I try going from 'edit' to 'home' state when url without hash value all is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711232/scroll-to-in-angularjs) things [have changed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4568) with angular 1.4. So if you use 1.4

```
function scrollTo(sectionName) {
    $anchorScroll(sectionName);
}
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes. I use angular 1.4.x.
Thanks, your solution is works for me.
And I want to find a reason why it happens, when try to redirect from state when $location.hash() is defined :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) If this solves your problem you should accept the answer to help others who may have the same problem.